# Error when Deploying a JSF application on Weblogic Server

Tags: weblogic, web-deployment, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c

I have a JSF application that is deployed using Tomcat Server it works flawlessly in Tomcat 7.
But now i need to Deploy the Very Application Weblogic 
I Deployed it to weblogic but after displaying the home page any link i try to open i get the error page displayed in my application.

I am using JPA as my persistence API to connect to Database.

Weblogic stack trace

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:27:39.135--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
<Mar 1, 2017, 5:27:40,136 PM IST> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is e
xecuted in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfp
b=true&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage.>
Mar 01, 2017 5:28:50 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListe
ner processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:00.619--ServerSession(3660206)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:00.625--ServerSession(3660206)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.31--ServerSession(3660206)--/file:D:/weblogic/wls
12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashboa
rdchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.349--ServerSession(3660206)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.35--No partition instance associated with curr
ent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.371--ServerSession(1037899)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.371--ServerSession(1037899)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.645--ServerSession(1037899)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.658--ServerSession(1037899)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.658--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.704--ServerSession(27423138)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:01.704--ServerSession(27423138)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.036--ServerSession(27423138)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.056--ServerSession(27423138)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.062--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.087--ServerSession(26245990)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.092--ServerSession(26245990)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.316--ServerSession(26245990)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.337--ServerSession(26245990)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.341--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.371--ServerSession(22959691)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.376--ServerSession(22959691)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.595--ServerSession(22959691)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.615--ServerSession(22959691)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.624--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.659--ServerSession(14950913)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.667--ServerSession(14950913)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.894--ServerSession(14950913)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.916--ServerSession(14950913)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.921--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.947--ServerSession(30389212)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:02.952--ServerSession(30389212)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.157--ServerSession(30389212)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.202--ServerSession(30389212)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.206--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.233--ServerSession(23849302)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.238--ServerSession(23849302)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.532--ServerSession(23849302)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.549--ServerSession(23849302)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:03.556--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.447--ServerSession(18058513)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.447--ServerSession(18058513)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.693--ServerSession(18058513)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.712--ServerSession(18058513)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.715--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.743--ServerSession(22199458)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:07.743--ServerSession(22199458)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.14--ServerSession(22199458)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.153--ServerSession(22199458)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.154--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.173--ServerSession(20468286)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.175--ServerSession(20468286)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.428--ServerSession(20468286)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.47--ServerSession(20468286)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.476--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.513--ServerSession(6774559)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.516--ServerSession(6774559)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.689--ServerSession(6774559)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.721--ServerSession(6774559)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.726--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.757--ServerSession(3757333)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.76--ServerSession(3757333)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.947--ServerSession(3757333)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.966--ServerSession(3757333)--/file:D:/weblogic/wl
s12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashbo
ardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:08.972--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.09--ServerSession(16566590)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.095--ServerSession(16566590)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.327--ServerSession(16566590)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.345--ServerSession(16566590)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.349--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.374--ServerSession(14747886)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.377--ServerSession(14747886)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.626--ServerSession(14747886)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.647--ServerSession(14747886)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.652--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.685--ServerSession(30423762)--EclipseLink, versio
n: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.689--ServerSession(30423762)--Server: 12.2.1.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.914--ServerSession(30423762)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test login successful
[EL Info]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.933--ServerSession(30423762)--/file:D:/weblogic/w
ls12212/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/Dashb
oardchartv1.0/x8ws98/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_Test logout successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-03-01 17:30:09.939--No partition instance associated with cur
rent SessionManager instance.
<Mar 1, 2017, 5:30:10,15 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@10
895055[app:Dashboardchartv1.0 module:Dashboardchartv1.0.war path:null spec-versi
on:3.1], request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@12f66ad[
POST /Dashboardchartv1.0/home.xhtml HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 112
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:7001
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
.8
Referer: http://localhost:7001/Dashboardchartv1.0/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-IN,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/home.xhtml - View /home.xh
tml could not be restored.
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.jav
a:212)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.jav
a:123)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am ot able to figure it out i am a newbe in weblogic please help

Comment: This is not jsf (nor jsf-2.2) related

Comment: @Kukeltje I know this is not related but as i am deploying it to weblogic i am not able to figure out how this is effecting my jsf code , i think it more to do with data source can you please some pointers

Answer (score 0):

This is because the jsf is not able to locate the view of home.xhtml based on the view state id in session.